# Copy files to libs folder as a part of build script

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk

I have an android application which uses jni and I'm trying to automate build process in Eclipse (using cdt plugin). I need to build my own static library, and I also need to use some precompiled libraries.
That means that I need to
a) build my own shared library (no problems here)
b) after build is complete, copy existing libraries into libs/armeabi folder (because this folder will be cleared during build process I must copy those files after every build)

I have some problems with b). What I'm trying to do is I'm inserting custom shell script (which works when executed as-is) after include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY) in Android.mk file. Unfortunately, this doesn't work, because apparently /libs/armeabi folder gets cleared only after Android.mk file is complete.

Is that true? Is there a way to insert post-build script into Android.mk? Is there any way I can execute bash script after jni code finished building but before whole build is complete (e.g. before java part is build and application starts executing?)? I though there must be some kind of "post-build" script in eclipse c/c++ project build settings, but there is no such thing.

Here's the complete Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)

LOCAL_MODULE    := player
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := player.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(shell ./copy-libs.sh) #this script will get called, but the files will be erased right after
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like there is an easier way to copy .so and .a libs without resorting to custom build scripts.
NDK supports prebuilt modules starting from ndk-r5, and they allow to copy .a or .so libraries into obj/lib folder during build process as needed.

Example and complete description are available in PREBUILTS.html file inside $NDK_INSTALLATION_FOLDER/docs/.

Comment: Note that the documentation seems not to be included with the NDK anymore but the information on prebuilts can be found here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts.html